# Encapsulating DbContext with using() on Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, uwp, entity-framework-core

I wanted to try to expose a DbContext instance through a get statement:

```
public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
    public SomeContext()
    {

    }

    public DbSet<SomeModel1> SomeModel1s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SomeModel2> SomeModel2s { get; set; }

   //etc
}

public class SomeInterfaceImplementation
{
    SomeContext ContextInstance { get; }
    //etc
}
```

But instead of using `ContextInstance` as a singleton, I want to do something so that calling `ContextInstance` actually does something like:

```
someVar = ContextInstance.SomeModel1s.Where(x => x.SomeID == externalID).OrderBy(x => x.SomeProperty).ToList();
//becomes the same as
using (var db = new SomeContext())
{
  someVar = db.SomeModel1s.Where(x => x.SomeID == externalID).OrderBy(x => x.SomeProperty).ToList();
}
```

basically, I just want to hide the using statement and create and dispose an instance of SomeContext every time ContextInstance is called. Hopefully I make sense. Does anyone have something in mind to do this?

Comment: What kind of application framework are you using? Asp.net core or?

Comment: @DannyChen I'm using this for UWP

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a very good idea, because there are some standard scenarios with `DbContext`. For example `DbContext` implements **Unit of Work** pattern so the `using` may be necessary.

But you can make what you want although is't not easy.

You need implement `IQueryProvider<TEntity>` interface and especially the generic method `Execute`:

```
public class EFDbSetProvider<TEntity> : IQueryableProvider<TEntity>
where TEntity : class
{
    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        using (dbContext = new DbContext())
        {
             return (TResult) dbContext.Set<TEntity>.Provider.Execute(expression);
        }
    }
}
```

Also you'll need implement corresponding `IQueryable<TEntity>` interface, but as I can see this implementation should be very simple.

```
public class EFQueryable<TEntity> : IQueryable<TEntity>
{
    . . .
}

public static class SomeContext
{
    public static EFQueryable<SomeModel1> SomeModels1 { get; set; }
    public static EFQueryable<SomeModel2> SomeModels2 { get; set; }
}

someVar = SomeContext.SomeModel1s.Where(x => x.SomeID == externalID).OrderBy(x => x.SomeProperty).ToList();
```

The `Execute` method will be called from `ToList`, then it will create `DbContext` and pass the assemblied expression to `DbSet<TEntity>.Provider.Execute`.

You may google "custom LINQ providers" or "IQueryable implementation example".
F.e. I found the article [Implementing a ustom LINQ provider](http://jacopretorius.net/2010/01/implementing-a-custom-linq-provider.html) so you can start here for details.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to look into this